Seek help for a more efficient way to use caching to train my lora model
When I was fine-tuning llama2 model using lora, I came across a problem.
The instruction dataset goes something like this:
"Here's the background to the problem... (1000 identical words)... Now answer the questions in context... (Different question, about 100 words)..." . 
Each piece of data has the same very long prefix.
As we know before, during inference, we can pre-computed and cache kv cache, and then pass the valuepast_key_value to speed up the reasoning.
like this
part0 = {}
for k, v in inputs.items():
    part0[k] = v[:, :-1]

output_part0 = model(**part0)

outputs = model.generate(
    **inputs, past_key_values=output_part0.past_key_values, max_new_tokens=5
)
print(tokenizer.batch_decode(outputs[:, inputs["input_ids"].shape[1] :]))

I figure there must be a more efficient way to use caching to train my model
. Can anyone give me a suggestion？Thanks a lot.
I figure there must be a more efficient way to use caching to train my model
. Can anyone give me a suggestion？Thanks a lot.
